# Sweet.js macro that calls a method

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I'm trying to write a `sweet.js` macro which needs to generate method call syntax, `obj.method()`, but the `method` is passed in to the macro as a literal expression. For example:

```
mcall(obj, toString().length);
// becomes
obj.toString().length;
```

I've got something that's close:

```
macro mcall {
  rule { ($o, $m:expr) } => { $o.$m }
}

mcall(obj, toString().length);
```

However, this apparently expands to this:

```
obj . ( toString ( ) . length );
```

Where are these extra parentheses coming from, and how do I get rid of them? Should I be using case rules and `#{}`? I tried permutations of that but still couldn't succeed at generating a method call without extra parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So currently in sweet.js tokens bound to an `:expr` pattern variable get wrapped in parens to help with getting precedence to work correctly. This is kind of a hack and will get fixed soon (some more discussion here: https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/issues/314).

The simple solution for your example is to just not use `:expr` since you don't really need it:

```
macro mcall {
  rule { ($o, $m ...) } => { $o.$m ... }
}
```

Side note: using `:expr` is technically wrong here since the RHS of a `.` is not allowed to be an unrestricted expression (eg `2+4` matches `$m:expr` but `obj.2+4` is a syntax error).

Comment: Thanks heaps! You're right, using an `expr` was technically wrong. I'm using this to [emulate Scala's placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177294/placeholders-for-anonymous-functions-in-javascript/24178372#24178372).